# Positioning absolute div below relative div

Tags: css, html, mobile

I am trying to develop a HTML5 app for mobile.
The layout is pretty basic header,content.

[image]

Header (red rectangle),content (green rectangle) are absolute divs.
The content must be scrollable if the height is bigger than the screen.

My problem begin when I'am trying to have the scrollbar on the orange rectangle div only (and not on orange and blue rectangle).

The orange rectangle div must begin at the end of the blue rectangle div and end at the end of the screen. The height of blue rectangle div is unknow and can change.

Actually blue and orange rectangle divs are correctly placed but the scrollbar is not positionned where I want.

So if I try to move the scrollbar with absolute positionning on orange rectangle div, it's overlap the blue rectangle div, if I use relative div to wrap the orange rectangle, the height of the wrapper equal zero cause of absolute children or the div run out of window and is unscrollable.

If someone has a solution, It will be nice.

**EDIT 1 :**

Here is the html and css code.

**html :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>YAOSWA</title>       
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="header_no_back_button" id="header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" ng-show="getShowHeader()">
            <span class="header_icon pull-left ng-hide" ng-show="getShowBackButton()">
                    <a href="#home">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </span>

            <span id="headertitle" class="pull-left ng-binding">
                    YAOSWA
                </span>

            <span class="header_icon pull-right" ng-show="getShowAboutButton()">
                    <a href="#about">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                </span>
            <span class="header_icon pull-right" ng-show="getShowSettingsButton()">
                    <a href="#settings">
                        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                    </a>
                </span>
        </header>

        <!-- ngView:  -->
        <div class="content main_content ng-scope" id="content" ng-view="" afkl-image-container="">
            <div class="home_template ng-scope">
                <div class="view container">
                    <div ng-hide="errorOverlay()">
                        <div class="weather_header" ng-show="currentWeather.city &amp;&amp; currentWeather.country">
                            <div class="weather_header_wrapper">
                                <div>
                                    <span class="current_weather_location ng-binding">New York / US</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="separator">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="weather_chooser">
                                    <span class="weather_type ng-binding">Hourly Weather</span>
                                    <span class="header_icon pull-left" ng-show="!isMinTab()">
                                <a ng-click="prevTab()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                </a>
                            </span>
                                    <span class="header_icon pull-right" ng-show="!isMaxTab()">
                                <a ng-click="nextTab()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </span>
                                    <div class="clear_both"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab_list">
                            <div class="tab ng-hide" ng-show="isActiveTab(0)">
                                ....
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab" ng-show="isActiveTab(1)">
                                <div class="weather_data_wrapper">
                                    <!-- ngRepeat: weather in hourlyWeather.list -->
                                    <div class="hourly_weather weather_data weather_803 day" ng-repeat="weather in hourlyWeather.list" ng-click="toggleWeatherDetail($event)">
                                        <div class="summary_info_hourly_weather summary_info_weather">
                                            <div class="row row_weather">
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="hourly_weather_logo_wrapper">
                                                            <div afkl-lazy-image-loaded="done" class="hourly_weather_logo" afkl-lazy-image-options="{&quot;offset&quot;: 150}" afkl-lazy-image="img/weather_icon_animate/icon_weather_hard_cloud.svg?numhourly=0"><img alt="" class="afkl-lazy-image" src="img/weather_icon_animate/icon_weather_hard_cloud.svg?numhourly=0"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <span class="hourly_weather_date_day ng-binding">Fri 31</span>
                                                        <span class="hourly_weather_date ng-binding">11:00</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div class="vcenter">
                                                        <div class="align-left">
                                                            <span class="hourly_weather_desc ng-binding">broken clouds</span>
                                                            <span class="hourly_weather_temp ng-binding">294.2 K</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end ngRepeat: weather in hourlyWeather.list -->
                                    <div class="hourly_weather weather_data weather_804 day" ng-repeat="weather in hourlyWeather.list" ng-click="toggleWeatherDetail($event)">
                                        <div class="summary_info_hourly_weather summary_info_weather">
                                            <div class="row row_weather">
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="hourly_weather_logo_wrapper">
                                                            <div afkl-lazy-image-loaded="done" class="hourly_weather_logo" afkl-lazy-image-options="{&quot;offset&quot;: 150}" afkl-lazy-image="img/weather_icon_animate/icon_weather_hard_cloud.svg?numhourly=1"><img alt="" class="afkl-lazy-image" src="img/weather_icon_animate/icon_weather_hard_cloud.svg?numhourly=1"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <span class="hourly_weather_date_day ng-binding">Fri 31</span>
                                                        <span class="hourly_weather_date ng-binding">14:00</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                    <div class="vcenter">
                                                        <div class="align-left">
                                                            <span class="hourly_weather_desc ng-binding">overcast clouds</span>
                                                            <span class="hourly_weather_temp ng-binding">297.91 K</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end ngRepeat: weather in hourlyWeather.list -->
                                    ....
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lazy-image.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css :**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'UbuntuM'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-font-family/0.80/Ubuntu-M.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'UbuntuR'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-font-family/0.80/Ubuntu-R.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu-light'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-font-family/0.80/ubuntu-light.woff'); /*URL to font*/
}



* {
    font-size:1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    color:#5c5c5c;
    font-family: 'UbuntuR'; 
}

.clear_both {
    clear:both;
}
.mediumfont {
    font-family: 'UbuntuM'; 
}


header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:60px;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ecedec;
    color:#5c5c5c;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #d7d7d7;
}

#headertitle,
.weather_header {
    font-family: 'ubuntu-light';    
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:42px;
}
.header_icon > a{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
}

#content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top:60px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ecedec;
    color:#000000;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding:5px;
}

#content .tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px;
}
#content .tab_list {
    /*
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    */
}

#content .tab,
.weather_data_wrapper {
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    */
}

/*
footer {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    padding:5px;
}
*/


.about_logo_wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.about_logo_wrapper > img {
    width:33%;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

.about_text_wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}

.about_title {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.about_template ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
}
.about_template ul li{
    margin:5px;
}

.about_desc {
    margin-top:35px 0px;
}


#errorOverlay,
#loadingOverlay {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:100
}

.error_overlay_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;        
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    margin-left: -50%; /*half width*/
    margin-top: -5%; /*half height*/
}

.loading_overlay_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;        
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left: -50px; /*half width*/
    margin-top: -50px; /*half height*/
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
/*
.hourly_weather_date_day,
.daily_weather_date_day,
.hourly_weather_desc,
.daily_weather_desc,
.detail_info_weather
*/
.hourly_weather_desc,
.daily_weather_desc {
    font-size:0.75em;
}
.weather_data,
.detail_info_weather,
.summary_info_weather {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}

.hourly_weather > .detail_info_weather,
.daily_weather > .detail_info_weather
{
    display:none;
}
.hourly_weather.show_weather_detail > .detail_info_weather,
.daily_weather.show_weather_detail > .detail_info_weather
{
    display:block;
}

.weather_data {
    padding: 5px;
}

.hourly_weather.weather_data,
.daily_weather.weather_data
{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.current_weather_desc,
.hourly_weather_desc,
.daily_weather_desc  {
    text-transform: capitalize; 
}

.detail_temp_min_max_group {
    display:inline-block;
}
.detail_icon {
    height:1em; 
}

.detail_icon_bkg {
    background-size: 18px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;   
}

.detail_icon_sunrise_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_sunrise.svg);
}
.detail_icon_sunset_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_sunset.svg);
}
.detail_icon_temp_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_temp.svg);
}
.detail_icon_temp_min_max_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_temp_min_max.svg);  
}
.detail_icon_pressure_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_pressure.svg);
}
.detail_icon_humidity_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_humidity.svg);
}
.detail_icon_cloud_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_cloud.svg);
}
.detail_icon_rain_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_rain.svg);
}
.detail_icon_wind_orientation_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_wind_orientation.svg);
}
.detail_icon_wind_speed_bkg {
    background-image:url(/img/details_icon/icon_wind_speed.svg);
}

.summary_info_current_weather {
    text-align:center;
}
.current_weather_logo {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}


/*black*/
.weather_data.weather_200,
.weather_data.weather_201,
.weather_data.weather_202,
.weather_data.weather_210,
.weather_data.weather_211,
.weather_data.weather_212,
.weather_data.weather_221,
.weather_data.weather_230,
.weather_data.weather_231,
.weather_data.weather_232,
.weather_data.weather_900,
.weather_data.weather_901,
.weather_data.weather_902,
.weather_data.weather_903,
.weather_data.weather_904,
.weather_data.weather_905,      
.weather_data.weather_906,
.weather_data.weather_950,
.weather_data.weather_951,
.weather_data.weather_952,
.weather_data.weather_953,
.weather_data.weather_954,
.weather_data.weather_955,
.weather_data.weather_956,
.weather_data.weather_957,
.weather_data.weather_958,
.weather_data.weather_959,
.weather_data.weather_960,
.weather_data.weather_961,
.weather_data.weather_962
{
    background-color:#000000;
}

/*blue*/
.weather_data.weather_300,
.weather_data.weather_301,
.weather_data.weather_302,
.weather_data.weather_310,
.weather_data.weather_311,
.weather_data.weather_312,
.weather_data.weather_321,
.weather_data.weather_500,
.weather_data.weather_501,
.weather_data.weather_502,
.weather_data.weather_503,
.weather_data.weather_504,
.weather_data.weather_511,
.weather_data.weather_520,
.weather_data.weather_521,
.weather_data.weather_522,
.weather_data.weather_531,
.weather_data.weather_600,
.weather_data.weather_601,
.weather_data.weather_602,
.weather_data.weather_611,
.weather_data.weather_621
{
    background-color:#55AAFF;
}

/*gray*/
.weather_data.weather_701,
.weather_data.weather_711,
.weather_data.weather_721,
.weather_data.weather_731,
.weather_data.weather_741,
.weather_data.weather_751,
.weather_data.weather_761,
.weather_data.weather_762,
.weather_data.weather_771,
.weather_data.weather_781,
.weather_data.weather_802,
.weather_data.weather_803,
.weather_data.weather_804
{
    background-color:#808080;
}



/*yellow*/
.weather_data.weather_800,
.weather_data.weather_801
{
    background-color:#E0B000;
}
/*night*/
.weather_data.night {
    background-color:#41403b;
}

.daily_weather_logo,
.hourly_weather_logo {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.weather_header {
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
}
.weather_header_wrapper {
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
.weather_header_wrapper > div {
    text-align:center;
}

.row_weather > div {
    text-align:center;
}

.row_weather {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.row_weather > div span {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.row_weather [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.align-left {
    text-align:left;
}

.weather_data .separator
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.separator {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.separator > span {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}

.weather_type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.weather_chooser {
    position:relative;
}


.container-centered {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.container-centered:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.elem-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    font: 16px/1 Arial sans-serif;        /* <-- reset the font property */
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code! please.

Comment: Hi Adam Buchanan Smith, I just add the code. I try to put only useful informations but maybe, there are still useless things.

Comment: I built a fiddle and added extra boxes to make it scroll however I do no see what your issue is, could you explain using this fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/v7r0j8hq/1/

Comment: Hi Adam Buchanan Smith, I try to have a scroll bar only on weather boxes, the div with "New York / US and Hourly Weather" must be "fixed" like the header without overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find a correct answer with html and css.

But javascript do the job. Just need to calculate the height of the header and add a "top" to the absolute div.